# How to use variable in promise? NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a shop-ecomerce website. I want to add product to my cart, so there are two circumstances
1. The product with that id is in the cart => add more quantity (SOLVED)
2. The product is not exist => create new one
So how to check if a product (with specific id) exist in cart? 
I use another variable (let exist) to check but it seems doesn't work (due to promise, I think)

```
// Add product to cart 
router.post('/add', checkToken, (req, res) => {
    let _idProduct = req.body._idProduct;
    let quantity = req.body.quantity;
    let exist = false;
    Cart
        .findOne({ user: req.decoded.userId })
        .exec()
        .then(cart => {
            cart.items.map(item => {
                // Product exist => add more quantity
                if (item.product == _idProduct) {
                    item.quantity += quantity;
                } 
            })
            // How to check if no product with that id in Cart ??
            cart.save(err => console.log(err));
            res.json({
                cart: cart
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err)});
})
```

Cart model

```
var Cart = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    items: [
        {
            product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
            quantity: { type: Number }
        }
    ],

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean/flag here to see if the item is found.

```
cart.items.map(item => {
   let found = false;  // boolean to see if we found the item
  // Product exist => add more quantity
    if (item.product == _idProduct) {
      item.quantity += quantity;
      found = true;  // if we find an existing item, set the flag to true
    } 
    if (!found){  // if the item isn't found, we can add it to the cart.
       // add item to cart
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure might make a bit more sense - instead of using map, you can filter your `cart.items` array to find the matching product. If it's there, increment the quantity. If not, add it to the array or whatever it is that you need to do.

```
.then(cart => {
   const existingItem = cart.items.filter(item => item.product == _idProduct)[0]
   if(existingItem) existingItem.quantity += quantity
   else { 
      //item does not exist, do what you need to do
   }
   cart.save(err => console.log(err));
   res.json({
     cart: cart
   })
})
```